# Python 2.7 RAW sockets: missing and wrong fields in ARP header

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, arp

at the beggining I would like to say that I didn't have any experiences with sockets earlier. I am trying to create response ARP packet in python 2.7. 
I have almost done it, but there's a problem: when I was looking at the packet in wireshark i found out that ARP header is missing sender & target mac and sender & target ip fields. Harware size and protocol size fields are wrong as well. What am I doing wrong? Do I pack data wrongly? Here is source code of the program:

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii


def formatMAC(mac):
    return mac.lower().replace(':', '')

def sendPacket(packet):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
    s.bind(("wlan0", 0))
    return s.send(packet)

eth_src = formatMAC('A0:88:B4:0A:A5:A8')
eth_dst = formatMAC("18:A6:F7:CF:51:B6")
eth_prt = '0806'

arp_hw_type = '0001'
arp_prt_type = '0800'
arp_hw_size = '0006'
arp_prt_size = "0004"
arp_opcode = '0002'
arp_mac_src = formatMAC('A0:88:B4:0A:A5:A8')
arp_ip_src = '192.168.0.134'
arp_mac_dst = formatMAC('18:A6:F7:CF:51:B6')
arp_ip_dst = '192.168.0.1'

eth_pack = struct.pack("!6s6s2s", binascii.unhexlify(eth_dst), binascii.unhexlify(eth_src), binascii.unhexlify(eth_prt))
arp_pack = struct.pack("2s2s1s1s2s6s4s6s4s",
         binascii.unhexlify(arp_hw_type), 
         binascii.unhexlify(arp_prt_type),
         binascii.unhexlify(arp_hw_size),
         binascii.unhexlify(arp_prt_size),
         binascii.unhexlify(arp_opcode),
         binascii.unhexlify(arp_mac_src),
         socket.inet_aton(arp_ip_src), 
         binascii.unhexlify(arp_mac_dst),
         socket.inet_aton(arp_ip_dst)
         )

packet = eth_pack + arp_pack
print(sendPacket(packet))
```

[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u9el.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you match up the Wireshark hexdump with what you're trying to send,  you'll see that the "hardware address size" and "protocol address size" fields of the actually sent packet are both 00.

This is because you passed two bytes to `struct.pack` (0006 and 0004) but you told it (with `1s`) to only format 1 byte, so it only outputs the first byte.

If you look at the hexdump you'll see that the addresses were actually sent, Wireshark just ignored them because the size was supposed to be 0.

Just change 0006 and 0004 to 06 and 04 as these are 1-byte fields.